# boost build finish with missing some files

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2010

my environment is next:
windows 7 ultimate x64
visual studio 2010 ultimate sp1

and using boost 1.55.0
get boost from boost.org (.zip) and follow next step to install

in administrator command :

```
c:\boost_download_folder>booststarp.bat

...

c:\boost_download_folder>b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 variant=debug,release link=static threading=multi address-model=32 runtime-link=static

...

c:\boost_download_folder>b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 variant=debug,release link=shared threading=multi address-model=32 runtime-link=shared
```

and it makes about 3g of files.
and i copied it to my project and include.

```
linker->general->Additional library directories : $(SolutionDir)\boost_1_55_0\lib;$(SolutionDir)\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib;  

c/c++->additional include directories : $(SolutionDir)\boost_1_55_0
```

everything succeess and header file finding is fine.
but only error happen it is

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib'
```

i find deep and deep and finally i found it. the builded library folder has no **libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib** file. i searched this file in Explorer but no **libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib** is included in **boost_1_55_0** folder.

but the next file is exist :

```
bin.v2\libs\system\build\msvc-10.0\release\address-model-32\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\libboost_system-vc100-mt-s-1_55.lib
stage\lib\libboost_system-vc100-mt-s-1_55.lib
bin.v2\libs\system\build\msvc-10.0\release\address-model-32\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi\libboost_system-vc100-mt-s-1_55.lib.rsp

bin.v2\libs\system\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-32\link-static\runtime-link-static-threading-multi\libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_55.lib
stage\lib\libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_55.lib
bin.v2\libs\system\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-32\link-static\runtime-link-static-threading-multi\libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_55.lib.rsp
```

i think it missed with build. what i missed?? please help me

Comment: vjam -j4 --without-python --without-mpi address-model=64 -toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage install

Comment: just cv the command and i worried about address-model=64